# Can't load extra xml in xslt

Tags: ios, xml, xslt, libxslt

I want to merge 5 xml files by xslt, in my swift app. I'm using libxslt to do this. In my xslt file, I have something like this

```
<xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="document('../dok_1_2.xml')/students/*" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="document('../dok_1_3.xml')/students/*" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="document('../dok_1_4.xml')/students/*" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="document('../dok_1_5.xml')/students/*" />
</xsl:copy>
```

And lib logs me errors in xcode

> I/O warning : failed to load external entity "../dok_1_2.xml"
>
> I/O warning : failed to load external entity "../dok_1_3.xml"
>
> I/O warning : failed to load external entity "../dok_1_4.xml"
>
> I/O warning : failed to load external entity "../dok_1_5.xml"

Files are in the same directory, and exists for sure.

If I delete `../` it doesn't make the difference only error looks like:

> I/O warning : failed to load external entity "dok_1_5.xml"

as a result of this operation, I receive, the xml file I use as a main file to run xslt.

UPDATE:

If I do something like this

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="document('/Users/xxxxxxxx/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/E57023BE-2794-425E-9153-408A10903112/data/Containers/Data/Application/008FF8B8-E258-4B93-92F0-4853B6552296/Documents/xxxxxx/158d661dd12adc16/MIND00200/dok_1_5.xml')/students/*" />
```

it means append full path to file it works:) but, I can't do it bacause path it's dynamic

Comment: Is your xsl stylesheet also in the same directory?

Comment: No it's in child directory, of xml's dir that's why I used `../`

Comment: I see, that would have been my suggestion

Comment: I don't know libxslt, but check that you are invoking it such a way that the processor knows the location of the stylesheet you are running. If you supply the stylesheet as a string, or as an anonymous input stream, or as a tree in memory, it's easy for the location information to be lost.